# How to resize every time for the same pixel value e.g.("10px") with jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wonder if there is any way to resize a `div` element for the same pixel value every time when i wanna resize the `div` element e.g.("10px"). I'm trying to do it with jquery-ui, i can resize but i wanna resize it every time for some pixel value, and with the same value reduce it.

```
$(children[0]).resizable({
    handles: "e, w"                               
});
```

I'm doing it with [resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/).
Anyone know if there is a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: what about `setTimeout(function(){ //resize }, timimg)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I got the question right, but I think you just need to use the `grid` param as such:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
  grid: 10
});
```

You can find the [documentation here](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#snap-to-grid)

Comment: So when i resize it i want to resize it every time for 10px.